# Shorthand for Combine's `compactMap { $0 }`

Tags: swift, combine

I want to add some syntactical sugar to my code & avoid typing out `compactMap { $0 }` every time I need to remove nil values from a publisher stream. Is it possible to make an extension that will let me just type `compactMap()`?

Answer (score 0):

I took some time today to find a clean solution:

Simply add the code below to your project and start using `.compactMap()` instead of `.compactMap { $0 }`

```
extension Publisher {

    // Note - you can name this function whatever you like, some people have suggested `compact()` or `compacted()` but I'll leave it like this because it addresses the original question.
    func compactMap<T>() -> some Publisher<T, Failure> where Output == T? {
        compactMap { $0 }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the `AnyPublisher` conversion here. `func removeNils<T>() -> some Publisher<T, Failure> where Output == T? { compactMap { $0 } }`

Comment: Great point - I also named it `compactMap` to shadow the original method name

Comment: Since there’s no mapping happening, how about calling it just  `compacted()`?